# Ruby Hash not converting to JSON in Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, hash

I'm using the Locu API and I've currently got the results from an HTTParty request into a ruby hash called data.

I've tried to call data.to_json, and this puts backslashes in my hash:

```
data.to_json
 => "{\"meta\":{\"limit\":25,\"cache-expiry\":3600}
```

Somebody else posted the same problem that was solved as follows:

```
puts data.to_json
```

Unfortunately, that does not alter my hash at all. Any ideas?

Comment: I assume, what you need to do is JSON.parse(data.to_json)

Comment: That is exactly what I need to do but for some reason it is not parsing my JSON.  It's not raising an error either--just returning the same hash.

Comment: `to_json` serializes (converts) data into a string JSON, so its working as expected. What are you trying to do with the json? Render it in a controller? Import it into the database? What's not working, exactly?

Comment: I want to be able to read it clearly in my console, so I can begin to add methods in my model with different endpoints from the API.  Right now, I can't read any of it, because it is one large block.  I thought turning it into JSON and parsing it would make it readable, so that I can begin to get more of a sense of what I am working with.

Answer (score 7):

> I've tried to call data.to_json, and this puts backslashes in my hash:

Two things: The output of that is not a hash. It's a string representing your Hash in JSON. Second, the backslashes are ok. It's only to disambiguate the double-quotes from the leading and trailing double quotes.

Instead of

```
data.to_json
```

do

```
puts data.to_json
```

Which will print as you expected:

```
 => {"meta":{"limit":25,"cache-expiry":3600}
```

Comment: I guess maybe I'm asking the wrong question.  Right now, my JSON is all in one large block, but I want it be able to parse it.   However, it is not responding to JSON.parse(data).

Comment: JSON is your data represented in a string. You are converting your hash to a string by doing `data.to_json`. If you want to parse it, you are converting a string to a hash. But why are you doing that when you already have `data` in hash form?

Comment: Because right now it is just one huge block of text and it's nearly impossible for me to begin to read the different keys and values.  I want to parse it to more easily access and visualize the data and get a sense of what my hash actually looks like.

Comment: you can do `require 'pp'`  and then `pp data`

Comment: That still returns a hash for some reason.

Comment: It returns a printy printed String representing your hash.

Comment: I see - what I meant is that it prints a string of your hash in human readable. If you want it returned do `str = JSON.pretty_generate(data.to_json)`

Comment: Seems like it's getting closer: I have this error now: JSON::GeneratorError: only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed

Comment: my mistake: `JSON.pretty_generate(data)`

Comment: THANK YOU!!! with a puts before it, it prints out perfectly--I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

It is [working as intended](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Generating+JSON).

What you've done is serialize a hash into a JSON `String`, used for passing data around via HTTP or something similar.

Comment: How can  I turn it into a JSON object?

Comment: So `JSON` isn't really an object, it's a notation. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). I think a better question would be what are you wanting to do with the `JSON`? That will help me help you.

Answer (score 0):

That's a serialized string so you will need to run

`JSON.parse(data)`

in order to convert it to JSON